# Swift enum not found in type error

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Here is my code in Xcode Playground:
[image]

Can someone tell me why this does not work, or what my error is?
I do not understand the error message because isn't `first` a type of `Test`?

Comment: remove the ! from the declaration of x since Test isn't an optional.

Comment: Thanks. I now see it. thanks guys. I guess it was a duplicate after all.
The error message Xcode gives is very unfriendly though.

Comment: Agreed. Swift still being in development itself has meant that the errors are often lacking :0-)